# Border on the left most part of a container

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having a problem on putting a border on the left most part of a section outside a container. I tried putting a margin-left on the container-fluid but the line should be inline with the section only. Right now the line is in the blue line. Please see image for better explanation.

[image]

Here's the current code

```css
    .store_details_item_wrapper {
        padding-left: 20px;
        border-left: 10px solid blue;
    }

    .store_details_img_wrapper {
        border: 5px solid black;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 15px; 
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="section-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row store_details_row">
          <div class="store_details col col-md-4 order-12 order-md-1">
            <div class="store_details_img_wrapper">
              <img class="store_details_img" media={props.fields.logo} />
            </div>
            <div class="store_details_item_wrapper">
              <div class="store_details_item">
                <i class="fa fa-clock" />
                Text here
              </div>
              <hr />
              <div class="store_details_item">
                <i class="fa fa-parking" />
                Text here
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="store_description col-12 col-md-8 order-1 order-md-12">
            <Image
              class="store_description_banner img-fluid"
              media={props.fields.herobanner}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please add your code

Comment: @XenioGracias sorry, it's now been added. I've also added the current position of the line (Blue). I'm trying to put it just like the orange line.

Comment: Without a working snippet is difficult to say anything. One thing that I see is that you have nested containers and in bootstrap you shouldn't really do that. Either .container-fluid or .container but not both

Comment: @Alvinrightback created a code snippet based on the code you have provided nut i cannot see any blue line.

Comment: @XenioGracias I've edited the code. Please run code snippet to see the actual position of the line

Comment: @Alvinrightback where you want the blue line to show??

Comment: @XenioGracias the blue line is the current position, i want it to put it in the orange line position in the image.

Comment: @Alvinrightback where is the orange line??.. please show screenshot so we can understand what you are expecting

Comment: @XenioGracias let me clear things out. There are 2 lines in the image but in the code there is only one right, the blue one. I'm trying to change the position of the blue line to the position of the orange line, overall there should only be 1 line, which is the orange line. I just put the blue line to show the current position of the line.

Comment: you want the blue line that is inside the container should position outside the container fluid??

Comment: @XenioGracias yes, btw I've changed the container-fluid to a wrapper class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used `border-left` this is 1 solution.

or you can use `position: absolute` and left with `negative` values to `.store_details_item_wrapper`

```css
.store_details_item_wrapper {
  padding-left: 60px;
  border-left: 10px solid blue;
  margin-left: -70px;
}

.store_details_img_wrapper {
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.container-fluid{
border: 2px solid black;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row store_details_row">
      <div class="store_details col col-md-4 order-12 order-md-1">
        <div class="store_details_img_wrapper">
          <img class="store_details_img" media={props.fields.logo} />
        </div>
        <div class="store_details_item_wrapper">
          <div class="store_details_item">
            <i class="fa fa-clock" /> Text here
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div class="store_details_item">
            <i class="fa fa-parking" /> Text here
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="store_description col-12 col-md-8 order-1 order-md-12">
        <Image class="store_description_banner img-fluid" media={props.fields.herobanner} />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```